# Can I rob my own stores for challenge completion?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

In the Saintsbook, there's a list of challenges to complete throughout the game. Pierce wants me to rob 15 stores for one of them. However, I'm wondering if this is a challenge I need to complete earlier in the game rather than later, before I have purchased most, if not all, stores in the game.

To that end, I'm wondering if I can rob my own stores after I've bought them and have them count for the challenge, or if I have to rob the stores before I buy them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can! What I do at my stores is rob the clerk, then after the alarm sounds I step outside, then go back in to clear my notoriety. After that, I can go about my business unmolested by the cops.

Comment: I was able to complete the challenge pretty quickly by robbing 2 of my own stores that were fairly close. I'd rob one, clear my notoriety, drive to the other, and rinse-repeat. By the time I drove back to each one, it had reset for robbing!

Answer (score 0):

Unless my game is glitching out, then their is no possible way to rob stores you own. Everytime I go into a store there is nobody at the counter or in the store anywhere. Not sure other people are having/had this issue but it is extremely frustrating!