# Is it possible to "win" a gang fight?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

After several gang fights, where I had to run to a shop in order to reset my reputation, I was wondering if it is possible in any way to actually win the fight.
It seems that once the fight has started, it will last forever (or until you die)...

Because you know, my character is awesome, I hate to have to run away or use tricks like calling for a reputation reset when there are too many enemies to handle...

I've seen it only once and it was during a "wave" event. Once everybody from the last wave is dead, it's over.
Can this happen for "random" gang fight ?

Answer (score 9):

If you get into a fight with random gang members off the street, the violence will continue to escalate until you do something to reset your gang stars.  The more of them you kill, the more "gang stars" you will get, and the more enemies will spawn.

Think of these gang fights like getting in trouble with the police in the GTA series - they will just keep coming, in larger waves and with more force, until you die or you lose your wanted level.

There are some challenges that require you to anger or fight with gang members, and sometimes getting into a random fight is the best way to finish these, but otherwise these fights don't earn you anything beneficial (perhaps aside from small boosts to cash and respect).

Comment: I was going to say the same, but I couldn't find any sources to quote for my answer.

Comment: These fights do earn you beneficial respect and money though, so that part of your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @MrSmooth, ehhhh, okay, I added that, but it's not a terribly profitable way to earn cash or respect in the game, to be honest.  I was more trying to point out that getting into these fights doesn't earn achievements or advance the game in any significant way.

Comment: I concur that a random fight is pretty much never beneficial, and will go on forever.  There is no concept of "winning" the random fights - but as agen86 points out there are some "non-random" fights that have benefits.  I'll also point out a) Later in the game, you can get buffs that auto decrease your gang rep rapidly, making the random fights end by themselves if you don't stoke the blaze actively.  b) Late in the game you can make yourself immune to nearly every form of death, making gang fights *like the buzzing of flies to me*.

Comment: For certain Saintsbook challenges, gang fights are useful as a mechanism to get a lot of gangsters localized in an area. Headshots and nutshots, taunting/complimenting gang members, and specialist kills all require the presence of gang members, and getting a swarm of Deckers or Morningstar around you before wiping rep at a shop is a good way to make progress on any of these. That last step *is* basically compulsory for most of the game, but it's important to appreciate gang fights for the opportunity they are, before the gangs vanish from the face of this dying earth.

Comment: @jsnlxndrlv, yep, that's why I mention "There are some challenges that require you to anger or fight with gang members, and sometimes getting into a random fight is the best way to finish these" in my answer.  It's possible to get gang kills even in a 100% complete game.  (see [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/40078/13845) for more on the subject)  This is all kind of tangential to the question, however.