# What are "GPS Shortcuts"?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

The other day I was driving around in Saints Row the Third and a message appeared just above the mini map saying "GPS Shortcut unlocked!"

What does this mean, what does it do and are there any other unlockable "shortcuts"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The GPS in Saints Row: The Third will generally give you shortest path directions to wherever your current objective or map marker is.  This GPS is represented by the green line on your radar, and you'll also see green arrows on the main display showing you turns you should take to get where you're going.  At the start of the game, however, it will only know about the major roads and thoroughfares of Steelport.

As you careen around the city, smashing through parking lots, alleyways, and other less-traveled paths, you will see this "GPS Shortcut unlocked!" message.  What it means is, that later, when the GPS is routing you through an area, it will know about this shortcut and use it in order to provide you with a shorter (but potentially not faster or safer, depending on the shortcut...) route.

Finding a number of these shortcuts is also one of the Saintsbook Challenges in your cell.  These challenges are also tied to the achievement "[You're my Hero!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40077/how-do-i-get-the-youre-my-hero-achievement)"  You don't need to find all of them for this challenge, I believe it only requires something like a quarter of the available shortcuts to finish.

You can see how many shortcuts there are and how many you've found on the phone.  Go to the "Extras" button, and then select "Stats" and move to page 5.  On my Xbox 360 version, there are 263 shortcuts to find.

Comment: I feel like there's a counter on the stats screen of the cell phone that tells you how many of these you've found, as well as the total number of shortcuts there are in the game.  It's been a while, though, so I'd have to go look that up.

Comment: @GarethJones, not a problem.  I <3 SR3!

Comment: @GarethJones, found the phone entry, if that's useful to you.

Comment: I want to add that even though those shortcuts might offer a shorter route, it's often slower. A friend and I were playing coop and when we were stealing cars and had to deliver them to a certain place, it was better to ignore some of those shortcuts, because you'd have to drive around more corners and such.

Answer (score 4):

Now that you already know what are GPS shortcuts, you might want a map of them.

LancetJades built such map and [posted in GameFAQs boards](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/954855-saints-row-the-third/61512561). The map is available here: http://www.evermoreforums.com/johnny/info/sr3_gpsmap.jpg

[image: Map of GPS shortcuts from "Saints Row: The Third"]