# Where are there cars with passengers in them?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

One of the challenges that I'm still sitting at zero for is "Hostages taken" - since every car I see only has a driver and no passengers.

Are there any areas where people are more likely to be car pooling?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40077/how-do-i-get-the-youre-my-hero-achievement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [my own experiences with this challenge:](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40077/how-do-i-get-the-youre-my-hero-achievement)

> I found the best place for this is near the Rusty's Needle tattoo shop that is northeast of Saints HQ. I don't know why this intersection is so profitable, but it is. Run in a circle around the intersection and look for cars. Parking minivans and other 4-door cars in the intersection sometimes helps spawn more of these.

There's a number of other tips in that linked answer, but I think this is the part most relevant to your question.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there are now special areas. Cars with multiple passengers are rarer then those with only one person, but still, every 10th or so car should have at least two passengers in it.

You have to be careful though to not Bo-duke-en into the car, because then you will often kick the person on the passenger seat out, too.

(I've completed the game with all challenges and achievements on Steam, so my answer is only from experience, not final proof.=